# Is there a lighter version of Google Analytics for Flash

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, google-analytics

40k of compiled code seems like a lot to me to be making some straightforward flash-javascript calls and makes GA unsuitable for banner ad work as well.

Does anyone know if there is a 'lite' version of Google Analytics for Flash?

Comment: How is 40k a lot??? I thought modems were extinct.

Comment: @bug-a-lot - you really want to live in a world where banners are larger than the sites they live on?

Comment: @bug-a-lot -  agreed 40k size IS relative, but if you're jumping thru hoops with preloading strategies, refactoring code etc, to keep initial load times low, AND all the compiled code for your entire app is under 100k, THEN 40k is simply unacceptable.

Comment: What about mobile connections in rural countries or subway? 56kbps is my best guest.

Comment: @bug-a-lot Many ad publishers set a 40kb limit on banner ads. We may both agree that the constraint may not be very large for today's standards, but until pubs increase their limit, we will continue having this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using directly the javascript functions? say:

```
ExternalInterface.call("pageTracker._trackPageview", "section/subsection");
ExternalInterface.call("pageTracker._trackEvent", "event", "cat", "label", "value");
```

Comment: Cay, yes I'm pretty sure thats the answer thought took some sleuthing on the GA pages to find this, and they only mention being able to call  pageTracker._trackPageview directly....

Comment: What is lost with this solution is the ability to make Google Analytics function calls without a corresponding Javascript implementation on the page (ie: in the case of a banner on another site). Yes, I definitely admit the size is an issue, but it eschews the need for the JavaScript file entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a lite version, similarly i don't believe google analytics intended its service be used for ad tracking.  That being said, you should try compressing your swf.  You can often shave off a big chunk of the file size especially from text source files.

http://www.compress-swf.com/
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/WEB-Design/Flash/swf-compressor.shtml

Comment: of course it is meant for ad tracking! It was born out of ad-words and ad-sense.

Comment: I agree with greg. GA was born out of urchin, and I don't think any of them were thought for banner tracking (or even flash). I would evaluate another solution more suited to your problem, like eyeblaster or something similar.

Comment: Event tracking definitely suggests this is designed exactly for ad tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Cay
That should work but how would you pass your custom account ID?

ie
If using the GATracker object

var myTacker=GATracker(containerdisplayObject,'customaccountID','Bridge',false)

Comment: My solution is only suitable if you have control over the HTML your swf is embedded in. I don't think there is a lite version of the AS3 library, but maybe it wouldn't be too hard to make a custom lite version yourself (you already have the source of the big one to get the procedures).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to track, why not just have the flash call home. Posting some variables to a script that loads them in a database?

```
var counter:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
counter.gamename = gametitle; //set variables here
counter.sendAndLoad("http://your script", result_lv, "POST");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform an ExternalInterface call from the flash back to the containing page.

Once you are back in the javascript you can use the javascript library that google provides to send custom events and page views back to google analytics.

It's important to distinguish between tracking events (typically a file download, a video being played, etc...) and pageviews. If you want to track navigation within a flash movie between different "pages" of flash content then you will probably want to use:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-XXXXX-X');
pageTracker._trackPageview('/flash/my_first_page');
```

Note that this will contribute to your overall page views count.

From google:http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncMigrationExamples.html

> Use the _trackPageview() method along with a URL you fabricate in
>   order to track clicks from users that do not lead to actual website
>   pages on your site. In general, we recommend you use Event Tracking
>   for tracking downloads, outbound links, PDFs or similar kinds of user
>   interactions. This is because virtual pageviews will add to your total
>   pageview count. However, if you want to configure goals based on
>   clicks to PDFs or downloads, you need to use this method (but be aware
>   that these clicks will be tallied as part of your overall pageview
>   count).